# QUNIT javascript require function global variable unchanged

Tags: javascript, undefined

Hi I am new to Javascript Qunit. Can you please tell me why global variable is not getting updated value out side the function.

Here is my code:

```
var x =0;

QUnit.test('myTest', function (assert) {

    require(["purchase"], function (purchase) {       
            x =  10;             
    });
    assert.equal(window.x, 10, "1 is equal to 1 : PASS");
//window.x value still showing 0;

});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried with the assert inside the require? It's an asynchronous call, by the time you call your test it hasn't finished assigning `x=10`

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks

Comment: Great, I've added it as an answer for future reference

Answer (score 0):

The `require` call is asynchronous so hasn't finished by the time your test runs, add the `asset` inside

```
require(["purchase"], function (purchase) {       
    x =  10;
    /* move the test inside the callback */
    assert.equal(window.x, 10, "1 is equal to 1 : PASS");             
});
```